# Change of two normal coordinates based on two nearby points?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, principal-bundles, connections

Let $M$ be a manifold and $L(M)$ be the [tangent frame bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_bundle#Tangent_frame_bundle) on $M$. Let $\Gamma$ be a [linear connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_(principal_bundle)#Formal_definition) on $L(M)$ which induces a [covariant derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_(vector_bundle)#Formal_definition) $\nabla$ on $TM$.

Let $p, q$ be two distinguished and sufficiently close points on $M$, connected by a smooth curve $\gamma = \{\gamma_t\}_{t\in[0,\epsilon]}$ so that $\gamma(0)=p$, $\gamma(\epsilon)=q$. Suppose that there is an open set $U\subset M$, such that $U$ contains $\gamma$ and is a [normal neighborhood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_coordinates#Geodesic_normal_coordinates) of both $p$ and $q$.

Fix a linear frame $u_p \in L_p(M): \mathbf R^d\to T_pM$. Let $u_q = \Gamma(\gamma)_0^\epsilon (u_p) \in L_q(M)$ be the [parallel displacement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_transport#Generalizations) of $u_p$ along $\gamma$, that is, $u_q$ can be joined to $u_p$ by a horizontal curve on $L(M)$ along $\gamma$.

Then we have two normal coordinate systems on $U$:
$$x=u_p^{-1}\circ \exp_p^{-1}: U \to \mathbf R^d,$$
$$y=u_q^{-1}\circ \exp_q^{-1}: U \to \mathbf R^d,$$
so that $(U,(x^i))$ and $(U,(y^j))$ are coordinate charts based on $p$ and $q$ respectively.

---

Now my **question** is: how to do change of coordinates between these two normal coordinate charts? More precisely, let $m \in U$, then what is the relation between $x(m)$ and $y(m)$?

If necessary, you can endow more structures to $M$. Say, $M$ is equipped with a Riemannian metric $g$ and $\nabla$ is the [Levi-Civita connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_connection), the frame bundle $L(M)$ is replaced by the [orthonormal frame bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_bundle#Orthonormal_frame_bundle) $O(M)$...

---

Some thinking: Clearly, $x(p) = y(q) = 0$. If $\gamma$ is a *geodesic*, then it is easy to check $x(q) = -y(p)$. Denote $\rho = x(q) \in\mathbf R^d$. Then I believe that $x(m) = y(m) + \rho$ for all $m \in U$. If $\gamma$ is *not a geodesic*, then I think that a curvature term should appear, since we may use the [holonomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomy#Ambrose%E2%80%93Singer_theorem). But I do not know how to prove my conjectures...

---

PS: This is a crosspost from [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4255699/change-of-two-normal-coordinates-based-on-two-nearby-points).

---

**EDIT:** I think there maybe no exact expressions for $x(m)$ and $y(m)$, but there should be an asymptotic expression with infinitesimals $o(\epsilon)$ or $o(d(x,y))$...

Comment: The shift property is not true. You can check this using $\mathbb{S}^2$ with the usual Riemannian metric. (Let $p$ be north pole, let $q$ be some point on the equator, and let $m$ be another point on the equator that is 90 degress from $q$.) You can see a bit of the complexity of the general problem by thinking about the infinitesimal analogue. This is issue of starting with $V$ a vector field along $\gamma$, and looking at the derivative of $\exp_{\gamma(s)}(V(s))$ with respect to $s$. You see then that this is related to Jacobi fields.

Comment: @WillieWong Thank you for the nice comments. You are right, the shift property does not hold in general. Inspired by the latter part of your comments, I think the problem is translated to find out the derivative of the map $t\to u_t^{-1}(\exp_{\gamma(t)}^{-1}m)$. But still, I do not know how to calculate this derivative via the Jacobi fields.

Comment: @WillieWong I think I know what you mean by making use of Jacobi fields. I am now going to try it. Thank you!

Comment: @WillieWong Inspired by your comments, I posted an answer under the [crosspost](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4255699/change-of-two-normal-coordinates-based-on-two-nearby-points). Thank you!